# Should I worry about a bot attack if my form doesn't actually post to an endpoint within a SPA application?

Tags: angular, forms, security, bots

I have built a form with fields for an email and password. The form doesn't actually POST anywhere; it simply calls a function when the form is submitted. I am using Angular, but I don't think that really matters for this question.

Should I be concerned about bot attacks? Should I protect the submission in some way (reCAPTCHA, honeypot, etc.)?

HTML

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="signIn(form)">
   <input type="email" />
   <input type="password" />
</form>
```

TypeScript:

```
public signIn(form: NgForm): void {
   ...
   //Call AWS Cognito endpoint to authenticate user.
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is - yes - you should be worried. This is actually also the reason why Cognito has deployed its [advanced security features](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pool-settings-advanced-security.html). The god thing is that addressing the issue should be more about cognito configuration than actual programming.

Comment: Thank you Marek. I was reading about the advanced security features. They seem pretty remarkable. ReCAPTCHA or a honeypot is easy to implement. I’m wondering if it would any value to a SPA application